# Get Address of Pointer in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I am debugging a program which is seg faulting. I want to know which memory space (heap, stack, etc) the pointer belongs. Is there any way to determine this in gdb?

Comment: Not sure if there's something built into gdb, but you can always look in `/proc/<pid>/maps`

Comment: Where is the pointer defined?  Local variable?

Comment: @FiddlingBits I worry about pointer only, I do not know how it born? though malloc or something else?

Comment: @username_4567 So, you only know the address. Gotcha.

Comment: @username_4567 Have you looked at this http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html? Have you tried the `stack` commands?

Comment: You want to know if the pointer itself is in stack / heap, or you want to know about the pointed-to object?

Comment: Look at the stack pointer and PC registers. If the pointer value is not close to the value of one of those registers, it is likely pointing to an address in the heap. (Otherwise it is pointing to stack or text.)

Comment: @markgz It could also be pointing to `.data`, `.rodata`, or another thread's stack. There are *way* too many places it could be pointing to to make this heuristic useful.

Comment: @username_4567 Watch point might help you catch the seg fault.

Answer (score 5):

> which memory space (heap, stack, etc)

Note that on any modern multithreaded system, there are *many* stack regions (one or more for each thread), and often many heap regions as well (e.g. glibc malloc will use `sbrk` *and* `mmap` to obtain memory pages from the OS. These pages will form disjoint sets).

> Is there any way to determine this in gdb

In general, no. On Linux, you can examine `/proc/<pid>/maps` and find a region that overlaps your pointer. GDB does not have any special commands to help you.